# How to tell an application to run on a specific .net runtime

Tags: c#, .net

In my development computer I have .net 3.0 and 3.5 installed.
I'm developing with vs2005 on .net FW3.0

How can I tell the application to use the 3.0 assembleis insted of the 3.5?

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use the config file:

```
 <startup>
  <supportedRuntime version="v3.0.3061"/>
 </startup>
```

something like that - check the actual version numbers.

hope this helps

Toby

Comment: reading the other answers and thinking about it, I'm not sure if this is right now ... vote it down if it's not please

Comment: Hi Rantri - try this : http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2005/07/12/438245.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you remove all referenced assemblies that are part of .NET 3.5 (such as `System.Core`, `System.Data.DataSetExtensions`, `System.Xml.Linq`). Look at the version of each referenced assembly in the Properties Window - if it is 3.5.0.0 remove it. As .NET 3.0 and .NET 3.5 use the same CLR (v2.0.50727) there's nothing else you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that I have done this is to use Project properties to target a specific .NET framework version.

In visual studio, go to the "Project" menu, then select Project Properties (usually at the bottom of the list).

There is then a drop down box called "Target Framework", which lets you choose from any of the frameworks compatible with your version of Visual Studio - eg 1, 1.1, 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0.  Select this, make sure that you remove references to libraries from newer frameworks as Darin says, and then build away.

Comment: I Visual stoudio 2005 you can't select the target .net framework.